# posts.models.Blog.DoesNotExist: Blog matching query does not exist

Tags: python, sql, django, slug

i am trying to use slug to navigate. here's the html tag

```
<a href="{% url 'blog_details' blog.slug|slugify %}">Read More</a>
```

urls.py

```
path('details/<slug:slug>/', views.blog_details, name='blog_details'),
```

models.py

```
slug= models.SlugField(max_length=264,unique=True,null=True,allow_unicode=True)
```

this is how i am creating auto slug

```
def Creating_blog(request):
    form=BlogForm()
    if User.is_authenticated:
        if request.method=='POST':
                form=BlogForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
                if form.is_valid:
                    blog_obj=form.save(commit=False)
                    blog_obj.author=request.user
                    title=blog_obj.blog_title
                    blog_obj.slug = title.replace(' ','-') + '-'+ str(uuid.uuid4())
                    blog_obj.save()
                    return redirect('index')
    return render(request,'blogs/creatingblog.html',context={'form':form})
```

this is the view of the blog details  page

```
def blog_details(request, slug):
    if User.is_authenticated:
        blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
        already_liked = Likes.objects.filter(blog=blog, user= request.user)
        if already_liked:
           liked = True
        else:
          liked = False
        comments=Comment.objects.filter(blog=blog)
        commet_form=CommentForm()
        if request.method=='POST':
          commet_form=CommentForm(request.POST)
        if commet_form.is_valid():
            comment=commet_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user=request.user
            comment.blog=blog
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog_details',kwargs={'slug':slug}))
        return render(request,'blogs/blogdetails.html',context={'blog':blog,'comment_form':commet_form,'comments':comments,'like':liked})
    else:
        HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
```

the problem is must be in

```
C:\Users\ITS\Desktop\blogger\Blog\posts\views.py, line 51, in blog_details
        blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

if i use pk=id instead of slug, it works. But whenever i am trying to catch with the slug the error rises. i am stuck for days here i can't find what's wrong.

Comment: remove the `|slugify` filter.

Answer (score 3):

By passing the slug through the [**`|sligify`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify) it might transform some slugs, such that linking to the original slug is no longer possible. You should remove the template filter, and work with:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog_details' blog.slug %}">Read More</a>
```

But regardless, slugifying yourself is *not* a good idea. You can use Django's [**`slugify(…)`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) to do this properly. The view also contains some problems, for example `User.is_authenticated` will always have truthiness `True`, and thus never fail, and [**`.is_valid()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid) is a method, so you need to *call* this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.text import slugify

@login_required
def creating_blog(request):
    form = BlogForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BlogForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.instance.slug = slugify(f'{form.instance.title} {uuid.uuid4()}')
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    return render(request, 'blogs/creatingblog.html', {'form':form})
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: You can make use of [**`django-autoslug`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/justinmayer/django-autoslug) to automatically create a slug based on other field(s).

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: I have got the solution and answered it down below. Can you please check it out.

Comment: @AbuRayhaN: you should simply recreate that `Blog` object with the `slugify` function as demonstrated above. The slug you created is not a valid slug...

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works. I have just made a little changes. The anchor tags

```
<a href="{% url 'blog_details' slug=blog.slug %}">Read More</a>
```

after changing this one other error was

```
NoReverseMatch at /blogs/
Reverse for 'blog_details' with keyword arguments '{'slug': '9Analysing-the-FIA-Rulebook-after-the-Abu-Dhabi-Grand-Prix-—-A-Lawyer’s-Perspective-9861e7b8-1c14-4fdd-abb6-e2d8398cf318'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['details/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

i changed the urls.py

```
path('details/<slug>/', views.blog_details, name='blog_details'),
```